# Error while inserting document in mongo shell

Tags: mongodb, insert, document

I am using mongo shell running in my ubuntu 18.04 machine. I am inserting document in the collections

I have tried creating multiple keys like for eg:
'db.Pricing.insert({key1:{key1a:value},key2:{key2a:value},                                  {key2b:value},key3:{key3a:value}})'

'db.Pricing.insert({Images: {"used in the book": 100}, Sheets: {"in the book": 0-20},Press book: [{"Medium": 10999},{"Large": 11999}],Flushmount: [{"Medium/Large": 17999}, {"Wide": 17999}], Magnum: {"All Sizes": 17999}})'

I expect the output to be inserting document in a collection but its an error as
'2019-07-02T12:23:52.153+0530 E QUERY    [thread1] SyntaxError: missing :     after property id @(shell):1:90'

Answer (score 0):

Check the json you are inserting at any json formatter like [JSONLINT](https://jsonlint.com/)

Comment: Thanks @Firdous. it worked after modification in the json

Answer (score 0):

`db.Pricing.insert({
    "Images": {
        "used in the book": 100
    },
    "Sheets": {
        "in the book": "0-20"
    },
    "Press book": [{
        "Medium": 10999
    }, {
        "Large": 11999
    }],
    "Flushmount": [{
        "Medium/Large": 17999
    }, {
        "Wide": 17999
    }],
    "Magnum": {
        "All Sizes": 17999
    }
})`

You have two mistakes,

1. Press book without quotes (since it has spaces it is important to
   wrap it in quotes)
2. Sheets: {"in the book": 0-20}, the value 0-20 is
   not a valid data type. It should either be an integer or make it as a string.

Also, in the first insert statement `db.Pricing.insert({key1:{key1a:value},key2:{key2a:value}, {key2b:value},key3:{key3a:value}})` {key2b:value} does not have a key. It should be like Key2:{key2b:value}. value is not defined, you must provide a value or wrap it in quotes

Comment: Thanks Vish. It got resolved after adding quotes in the string type